# mmenu not closing on link pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on another mobile website which has the mmenu installed, all works fine as far as the scroll opens to show the menu, but all the menu items are external links. When I tap/click an external link the page will hyperlink to the page selected without closing the menu first. Is there anyway of making the menu close before loading the external links?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu").mmenu({
            classes: "mm-zoom-panels",
            counters: true
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="page"><a href="main.asp">
        <img border="0" src="../images/header.png" width="100%"></a>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#menu"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <div align="center">
    </div>
</div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="main.asp">Today</a></li>
                <li><a href="times.asp">Times</a></li>
                <li><a href="setting.asp">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.asp">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    classes: "mm-zoom-panels",
    counters: true,
    onClick: {
        close: true
    }
});
```

for more info see this:-http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/options/
thanks

Comment: I tried the above code and on my local pc it works fine but when I publish the site on the web I tap/click an external link and the menu will close a little before hyperlinking to the page selected. Is there anyway on having a delay to allow the menu to close completely before hyperlinking.